# Exit Man opened from the touch bar

Tags: terminal, touch-bar, command-line

So in terminal there is a fun feature now, as you can open a `man` page of the current command by using the touchbar. I failed to close the man page though. The usual `q` did nothing as well as `esc` or `CTRL-C`. Does anyone know how to close it?

Answer (score 2):

It might have to do with the order of keys that you were typing that prevented `q` from working when you were trying to find the key to exit out of the manual.

If you press the `ESC` key it writes to the screen and the last line goes from `END` to `ESC`. If you then press `q` it doesn't close the manual but it will switch it back to `END`. Press `q` again and it should exit you out. Keep pressing `q`.